Is there an image viewer that prioritizes keyboard and mouse events over rendering
I'm looking for an image viewer that will not drop any keyboard or mouse events; I'm often browsing directories with lots of high resolution pictures, and the ones I' ve tried so for (eog, xviewer) don't honor all the keystrokes / or / insist on decoding entirely each image in the sequence. The viewer completely drops all the pending keystrokes or mouse events when it's decoding the current image.
To be clear, if I' m at image zero, and I send 50 mouse mouse up events, I expect the viewer to start on decoding the 50th picture ASAP

Have you tried GNOME's default Image Viewer (Loupe)? You can switch images while images are loading in the background, the UI is updated with the correct filename immediately. If a running decoding operation is no longer needed, the operation is cancelled.
